# How to pre-populate a 'date' input field with Razor/C# values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a 'date' type input, and I'm trying to get the Razor code to pre-fill the date with information that the server already has, because it's for an Edit field on an MVC ASP.NET Core app I'm working on.

The code I'm using is:

```
<input type="date" name="DeliveredDate" id="DeliveredDate" value='@Model["order"].DeliveredDate.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy")'>
```

I can get the code to show the string in any other part of the page, but is there a trick to getting that same string to populate the value of a date field? All my googling hasn't turned up anything particularly helpful.

Comment: What is displayed with the current code?

Comment: Sounds like you need this one: `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DeliveredDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "someclass", type = "date" })` or `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DeliveredDate)` with `DateTime` property.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya nothing is currently displayed other than "mm/dd/yyyy" in the field.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto sorry, I'm new to this, can you explain that in a bit more detail please?

Comment: Can you confirm the model is correctly populating?  Try rendering `@Model["order"].DeliveredDate.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy")` inside a simple `<p>` element, or inspect the Model by setting a breakpoint.  Is there any javascript or CSS interfering with the input element?

Comment: @Khyron it's properly populating. 

Turns out the command requires should look like this: @Model["order"].DeliveredDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

But then I found out my dates were actually outside the range that can be populated in HTML, since the dates were just 0001-01-01, as opposed to some range I found (something like the 1970's to 2049?) that's able to be populated in the value section.

Comment: @glitchwizard Ok, so you're using the native HTML5 datepickers.  In that case the date format matters and is described in the HTML spec.  Glad you found the cause but I thought it worth mentioning that the range restriction is not from HTML.  HTML can handle any date range that C# can handle.  The limit could be coming from a database?  SQL Server's `datetime` is limited to January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either `@Html.TextBox()` or strongly-typed `@Html.TextBoxFor()` helper to do so, by either setting `DisplayFormatAttribute` or date format directly in the helper:

**Viewmodel property**

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime DeliveredDate { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
@Html.TextBox("DeliveredDate", Model["order"].DeliveredDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { type = "date" })

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DeliveredDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { type = "date" })
```

Or using `EditorFor` by setting date format, which automatically appends `type = "date"` attribute:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DeliveredDate)
```

If you're using tag helper, just set `asp-for` attribute:

```
<input asp-for="DeliveredDate" type="date" />
```

**Notes:**

1) Make sure that you're already set the date value inside controller action, e.g. `model.DeliveredDate = DateTime.Now` (`model` has type of `Model["order"]`).

2) The latter approach requires setting `DisplayFormatAttribute` in viewmodel property because there's no string formatting parameter to set the format from `EditorFor` or tag helper itself.

Comment: Thank you! 

Actually it turns out the command requires should look like this: @Model["order"].DeliveredDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") But then I found out my dates were actually outside the range that can be populated in HTML, since the dates were just 0001-01-01, as opposed to some range I found (something like the 1970's to 2049?) that's able to be populated in the value section.

Answer (score 3):

The correct command ended up being

```
@Model["order"].DeliveredDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

but then I learned from my instructor that there's a date range that is able to be displayed, and it varies with different platforms, but I'm pretty sure the range that can be displayed is between the years 1950, and 2049.

Once I actually set the dates it was supposed to display to one that was within that range, it worked, and if I tried to display a date outside of that range, it would break again.